# Compare class name with variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input element with class names like

```
<input class="so os us">
```

what I want to do is if a variable matches a particular class name then do something

```
$(function(){
   var x="os";
   var y=$("input").attr("class");
   if(x=y){
    //since the class name contains the word "os" it has to perform the actions mentioned here
   } 
});
```

I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Print the variable `y` on the screen, using `alert` or so. Then you will see, why the `x` does not match `y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.hasClass()`:

```js
$(function() {
  var x = "os";
  var y = $("input").hasClass(x);
  if (y) {
    $('input').val('foobar!!!').css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="so os us">
```

Comment: thank you bro I was trying search but this is very easy

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `hasClass` function.

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/